# Seeking ranslation for "Seek discomfort" in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Salvete!

I am currently looking for a translation of the phrase "seek discomfort" into Latin. I am aware that Latin is a rich and nuanced language, and I would greatly appreciate the insights of the community here on Stack Exchange Latin.

The phrase "seek discomfort" carries a connotation of intentionally embracing challenges and stepping out of one's comfort zone in order to grow and learn. It is often associated with personal development, resilience, and the pursuit of new experiences.

Thank you in advance,
Valete!

Comment: Nice English connotation.